# Android drawables work in Debug but become black squares in Release

Tags: android, flutter, apk, android-drawable

I'm working on an Android app (written in Flutter but I don't think it matters) which uses a drawable called `quick_plus.png` as shown here:

[image]

It works great in debug mode.

But not in release mode, where the `quick_plus.png` drawable became a black square. After unzipping my APKs I confirmed that's also what they contained, just a black square:

[image]

No idea if this is relevant, but I generated those APKs by following the [bundletool docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool#generate_apks):

```
bundletool build-apks \
--bundle=build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab \
--output=build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.apks \
--ks=... \
--ks-pass=... \
--ks-key-alias=... \
--key-pass=...

bundletool install-apks --apks=build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.apks
```

Here's my `build.gradle` release config:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

and the `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
-keep class com.dexterous.** { *; }
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem!

It was due to Android [shrinking and obfuscating](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-resources) my code. All I had to do was add a file called `android/app/src/main/res/raw/keep.xml` with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:keep="@drawable/quick_plus" />
```